# Call a method in codebehind of view, prior to program exit

Tags: wpf, mvvm, richtextbox

I'd like to call a method in a view, just prior to program exit. My ViewModel has a method CleanUp that gets called prior to program exit that can commit changes from the ViewModel, but it cannot call a method in the view.

I've had to place a small amount of logic in the view for the for the document property of a richtextbox. An attached property did not work well in this case because every time content changed in the richtextbox a new representation of a FlowDocument would need to be created and I could not see the sense in such an overhead.

I am just looking for a way to call the method in the view when the application is about to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about subscribing to the Application.Exit event?

Comment: Ok, I'll search for an example of how to register for this event.

Comment: I got this to work by adding the following in the constructor of the view Application.Current.Exit += new ExitEventHandler(Current_Exit); and handling the Current_Exit method. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You could just raise an event from your VM and have your view attach to that event.